# Azure error: : No HOME path available

Tags: azure

I am running a command through Adapter and it gives below errors:

> error:   No HOME path available
>               C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI\lib\util\utils.js:730
>                 throw new Error('No HOME path available');
>                       ^
>               Error: No HOME path available
>                   at Object.exports.homeFolder (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Azure\CLI\lib\util\utils.js:730:9)
>                   at Object.exports.azureDir (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI\lib\util\utils.js:737:23)
>                   at AzureCli.*.extend.getErrorFile (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Azure\CLI\lib\cli.js:119:28)
>                   at AzureCli.*.extend.recordError (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Azure\CLI\lib\cli.js:124:28)
>                   at process.self.uncaughExceptionHandler (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Azure\CLI\lib\cli.js:105:14)
>                   at process.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
>                   at process._fatalException (node.js:272:26)

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to provide the detailed steps and environment which could reproduce your issue?

By checking the line of source code which throw this error as shown below, it seems obvious that it is due to MISSING HOME path and HOME drive environment variable.

```
exports.homeFolder = function () {
  if (process.env.HOME !== undefined) {
    return process.env.HOME;
  }

  if (process.env.HOMEDRIVE && process.env.HOMEPATH) {
     return process.env.HOMEDRIVE + process.env.HOMEPATH;
  }

  throw new Error('No HOME path available');
};
```

You should be able to solve this by setting the two new missing environment variables as below:
**HOMEDRIVE=C:**

**HOMEPATH=\Users\yourusername**

Comment: Setting environment variables worked for me. In my case this was a build agent on a build server, so it's not surprising the environment variables weren't set as they are scoped to the user level, not system level.